# What is the meaning of a constant in a SELECT query?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Considering the 2 below queries:

1)

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
SELECT a.ProductID, a.ListPrice
FROM Production.Product a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail b
          WHERE b.ProductID = a.ProductID)
```

2)

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
SELECT a.ProductID, a.Name, b.SalesOrderID
FROM Production.Product a LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail b
ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID
ORDER BY 1
```

My only question is know what is the meaning of the number **1** in those queries? How about if I change them to 2 or something else?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Have you tried it? Have you noticed a pattern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first case it does not matter; you can select a 2 or anything, really, because it is an existence query.  In general selecting a constant can be used for other things besides existence queries (it just drops the constant into a column in the result set), but existence queries are where you are most likely to encounter a constant.

For example, given a table called `person` containing three columns, `id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, and `birthdate`, you *can* write a query like this:

```
select firstname, 'YAY'
from person
where month(birthdate) = 6;
```

and this would return something like

```
name     'YAY'
---------------
Ani       YAY
Sipho     YAY
Hiro      YAY
```

It's not useful, but it is possible.  The idea is that in a select statement you select *expressions*, which can be not only column names but constants and function calls, too.  A more likely case is:

```
select lastname||','||firstname, year(birthday)
from person;
```

Here the `||` is the string concatenation operator, and `year` is a function I made up.

The reason you sometimes see `1` in existence queries is this.  Suppose you only wanted to know whether there was a person whose name started with 'H', but you didn't care who this person was.  You can say

```
select id
from person
where lastname like 'H%';
```

but since we don't need the id, you can also say

```
select 1
from person
where lastname like 'H%';
```

because all you care about is whether or not you get a non-empty result set or not.

In the second case, the 1 is a column number; it means you want your results sorted by the value in the first column.  Changing that to a 2 would order by the second column.

By the way, another place where constants are selected is when you are dumping from a relational database into a highly denormalized CSV file that you will be processing in NOSQL-like systems.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand what u said about the first usage of 1. For the second, I understood.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case the `1` is not a literal at all. Rather, it is an ordinal number, indicating that the resultset should be sorted by its first column. If you changed the `1` to `4` the query would fail with an error because the resultset only has three columns.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, the reason you use a constant like `1` instead of using an actual column is you avoid the I/O of actually getting the column value. This may improve performance.